# how to update database column based on answer in ruby on rails 4 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a quiz app that I have been working on in an attempt to learn more about Ruby on Rails.  Right now it will tell if answer is correct and then move onto next question presenting a percentage at the end.  I want to also add points for every correct answer.  I have a points column in the users table in the database but can't seem to connect the dots on how to increase that number by 1 for each correct answer.

the def for the answer method in the controller is below.  I am new to this but my gut is telling me I need to put the code under the if statement, am I correct on that?  Can anyone help me out with how I would increase the number in the points column for the currently signed in user by 1 based on a correct response?

Thanks for any help.

```
   def answer
    @current = session[:current]
    @total   = session[:total]
    choiceid = params[:choice]

   @question = session[:question]
   @choices  = session[:choices]

   @choice = choiceid ? Choice.find(choiceid) : nil
   if @choice and @choice.correct
     @correct = true
     session[:correct] += 1
   else
     @correct = false
    end

   session[:current] += 1
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

> current_user.increment!(:points)

Comment: wow I must have tried every variation of that but this one, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you need smth like this

```
if @choice and @choice.correct
  @correct = true
  session[:correct] += 1
  current_user.increment(:points)
else
  @correct = false
end
```

Method [`increment`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/increment) add 1 to current value (or initialize value with 0 and add 1).

---

But I suggest you another schema. The problem of your current system: it does not have "history". You will not manage to say what answers user has, what answers are correct, when user answers it and etc.

I suggest to create several tables:

```
#User: 
has_many :answers

#Quiz:
has_many :questions

#Question:
belongs_to :quiz
has_many :answers

#Answer:
belongs_to :quiz
belongs_to :question
belongs_to :user
```

In the model Answer you can save real answer, points, timestamp etc. To calculate user points for a quiz: `Answer.where(user_id: user.id).where(quiz_id: quiz.id).sum(:points)`.

PS suggested schema is just an idea and can be modified for exactly your requirements.

Comment: thanks so much for the detailed answer.  I have all that stuff in place, it was really just the wording of it that I missed.  This will be a great answer for someone looking to build something like this as this is how the model relations are set up.